# Issue in importing file on eclipse during building application

Tags: android, eclipse

They Say "It will create a folder CSipSimple where source code from CSipSimple and all svn dependancies has been gathered. CSipSimple also now depends on the ActionBarSherlock library. So the second line also checkout the ActionBarSherlock copy for current csipsimple version. When you'll import to Eclipse (if you do), you have to import ActionBarSherlock as well. "

I got this line from [CSipSimple](http://code.google.com/p/csipsimple/wiki/HowToBuild) . I cant import ActionBarSherlock  file on eclipse.
It can't be import because it doesn't have any projects , it showing .
I need this file so please help me out to debug it . If any one knows full installing steps of this CsipSimple build application then please help me .
I am using Linux OS platform.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you should join de developer google group (http://groups.google.com/group/csipsimple-dev/).

Indeed, I do not commit the eclipse project files on the actionbarsherlock project. So you have to create a new android project and import from the folder you checked out just before.

As target android api select android 13 (it's the current of ActionBarSherlock) and tell that it is an android library.

If everything goes well you should see ActionBarSherlock project in your eclipse projects. From this point, if you built the native library previously and it succeeded you should be able to run the project.

Comment: Regarding your post on the dev list your problem is about building ffmpeg lib :). Lets continue on the dev list. It will be easier to share infos about how to build to other that may encounter the same problem than you :).

Answer (score 1):

1) check out the project - not a android project yet

2) copy the project folder to some other place

3) delete the project you checked out in no(1) entirely (need to check the box in dialog)

4) create new project -> select 'Android Project' -> select 'create project from existing source'

-> browse the place you copied

5) now you will see android project created.

Answer (score 0):

I checked out.

Just check out and copy the project to some other place.

and in 'Create New Project' window, select 'create from existing source' and select your copied folder.

Comment: delete the current project entirely.

Comment: Can u elaborate a little please .. which project to delete and i havn't install any project yet